# Data integrity when AES key can be modified

Tags: aes

I found a client-server application where the server creates a random AES-256-CBC key, and gives this key to the client for use as an authentication token. The key is used on the server to encrypt a string describing the user's privilege level, for which the ciphertext is stored on the server in a file that cannot be accessed/modified in any way by the client. When the user sends the key to the server in a request, it is used to decrypt the file on the server in order to retrieve the user's access group.

I am familiar with attacks where the user has control of the ciphertext (e.g. in a cookie), and can modify the IV to modify the resultant plaintext that results on the server. This type of attack would be useful in my scenario in order to perform privilege escalation.

However, by changing the key only, the entire plaintext is changed, if it is even decryptable at all.

So, can the decryption result be usefully modified by changing the key? Even if I can change one letter deterministically, that would be useful. I was not able to find any examples of this scenario online, and am not sure if it has a name.

Comment: How do you find the correct key? The server, if written correctly, will notice the attack, and the user's data with another key will produce useful information with only negligible probability.

Comment: @kelalaka The server gives the AES key to the client, if that's what you are asking. I don't think there is any validation for this sort of thing on the server.

Comment: Does the server keep the key? What is the guarantee that an attacker cannot change the file that stores the ciphertext? A successful attack can be executed to increase the leverage. It was proposed in the CryptDB attack paper that swapping the columns is enough.

Comment: @kelalaka no, I do not think the server keeps track of the key. An attacker would need to get root access to modify the file directly, in this particular case.